# make error: invalid command line option

Tags: matlab, gcc, makefile, mingw, mex

I'm trying to make http://iridia.ulb.ac.be/~manuel/hypervolume (version 2.0) on windows using the instructions they've given in their README which is to install MINGW and run "make mex", however I keep getting this error:

```
$ make mex
mex  -D VARIANT=4 Hypervolume_MEX.c hv.c
mex.exe: Invalid command-line option
mex.exe: Data: unknown option
make: *** [mex] Error 1
```

instructions given:

> - Guillaume Jacquenot contributed a MEX interface for MATLAB
>     (Hypervolume_MEX.c). Use `make mex` to compile it.

Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: The instructions you link to say to type `make`, not `make mex`.

Comment: Mat, this was bad communication on my part. I am following the README file to create the Matlab interface, I've made an edit with that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within matlab change directories to the location of the hypervolume code, then run

```
mex -DVARIANT=4 Hypervolume_MEX.c hv.c avl.c
```

at the matlab command prompt. If your c compiler is set up correctly within matlab this should generate an executable named Hypervolume_MEX.xxx (dll in my case).

**edit**
I used the matlab compiler (Lcc C 2.4) on Matlab 7. No luck with Visual Studio 6 or Watcom 10.6 compilers (although I did not attempt to debug).

Comment: This worked for me producing `Hypervolume_MEX.mexw32`: `mex -largeArrayDims -DVARIANT=4 Hypervolume_MEX.c hv.c`, besides I don't see a file named `avl.c`. You don't necessarily need MinGW, just a [supported compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013a/index.html) (I used Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: @Amro  did you download `hv-1.3-src`, it includes `avl.c`. I compiled to a dll (win XP) which operates as it should according to the suggested demos. I didn't even check the compiler but it did not bat an eye.

Comment: ah, the OP mentioned version 2.0 which is what I used. As for the MEX file extension, MATLAB has [changed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB#Release_history) quite a bit since R14 :)

Comment: Hi @TryHard, I solved this issue earlier today and it was the same solution as yours. Thank you. I can't vote you up due to permissions but I marked you as answered.